# 404 not found error in styling the action bar page in android page

Tags: android

I am trying to read more about android [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) from the android developer site however I am getting error 404: Not found. Is it something problem in my connection ? is there a good place where I can read more ?

Comment: Cached version is here: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:KR4MfaZf9FcJ:https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk

Comment: @SanjayVerma yes thats a working around. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like multiple people have reported this issue, and seems to be a google side problem.

1. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=158210&q=404%20error&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars
2. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177324&q=404%20error&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars
3. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=94485&q=404%20error&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

I've opened a new issue here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190527&thanks=190527&ts=1445110534

Meanwhile, you can continue to use cached version, e.g.
'http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:KR4MfaZf9FcJ:https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk

[UPDATE]
I found this to be helpful for opening cached URLs: http://cachedview.com/

Thanks.